# dpkg -L shows almost no files in apt libboost-all-dev package

Tags: apt, dpkg, boost

I installed Boost library on my ubuntu 18 using apt:

`sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`

however, I cannot find boost library files on my machine. When I try:

`dpkg -L libboost-all-dev`

the output is:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libboost-all-dev
/usr/share/doc/libboost-all-dev/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libboost-all-dev/changelog.gz
```

No headers, no `.so` files! Am I doing something wrong? 
I'm getting the compilation error:

`/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lboost_random-mt`

Comment: Because the actual files are provided by the dependencies, which are version-specific dev packages: [`libboost-all-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libboost-all-dev) depends on [`libboost-chrono-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libboost-chrono-dev) depends on [`libboost-chrono1.58-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libboost-chrono1.58-dev), which contains the actual files.

Comment: @muru write your comment as answer. Do not forget to add link to the [file list of `libboost-all-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libboost-all-dev/filelist).

Comment: @N0rbert wouldn't help with OP's actual problem (the missing random-mt library).

Comment: @muru, right, did not see this point. @Przemysław Czechowski - are you sure that you need `-mt` suffix? Asking because of the fact that [`libboost_random.*`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libboost%20random) is available.

Comment: @muru, I see, dependencies explain everything! So `dpkg -L` is not the perfect tool to see what files I installed. I would accept it if you write it as an answer.

Comment: @N0rbert yes, removing `-mt` already solves the problem. I've learned that this is removed, because newer version of boost are already thread-safe by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from [the list of `libboost-all-dev` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libboost-all-dev/filelist) it contains only two files. It is normal.

But it has very long [list of dependencies](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libboost-all-dev).

About your `libboost_random` libraries. You can find them in [`libboost-random1.58-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libboost-random1.58-dev/filelist) and [`libboost-random1.62-dev`, `libboost-random1.65-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=bionic&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=libboost_random.a&searchon=contents) packages.

But the most safe way will be install them as dependency of [`libboost-random-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libboost-random-dev) as dependency of `libboost-all-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

So Boost packaging looks very complicated ...

Comment: `libboost-all-dev` will bring in `libboost-random-dev` too.