# Unable to remove Boost library files?

Tags: apt, gnome-terminal, uninstall, libraries, boost

I have done `apt-get remove libboost-all-dev` command. But, I can still see a directory  `/usr/include/boost`. I want to remove everything related to Boost. How do I do this?

Comment: Related: [dpkg -L shows almost no files in apt libboost-all-dev package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059916/dpkg-l-shows-almost-no-files-in-apt-libboost-all-dev-package)

Comment: Ask the packaging system: `dpkg -S /usr/include/boost`

Comment: @waltinator I have removed the directory, but I can still see some libraries of libboost when I do ```sudo apt-get purge libboost-``` and press tab. I would like to remove all of these libraries, how to do it?

Comment: Upon further inspection, I found that some of the file are in the directory ```/usr/share/lintian/overrides``` and also in ```/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu```. Should I remove it or not?